# Can we disable stateful ftp inspection just for one program?

Tags: windows, firewall, ftp, tls

Right now I have a program which generates ftp requests to a remote server. The connection is `passive` mode. The problem is that the connection is encrypted with `TLS` and windows firewall on the client side terminates the connection as it is unable to do stateful inspection of the ftp connections.

The solution to this is to disable the stateful inspection with the following command:

```
netsh advfirewall set global statefulftp disable
```

Can I add an exception or an outbound rule in the windows firewall so as to disable the stateful inspection just for that particular program only? Is it possible to do so. My target is to have default settings for other programs and relaxed setting for my program.

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft itself says in its documentation for  
[Using Windows Firewall with secure FTP over SSL (FTPS) traffic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings-in-iis-7#using-windows-firewall-with-secure-ftp-over-ssl-ftps-traffic) that disabling stateful inspection is the only solution.